# Splitting a string and loop through the variables

Tags: batch-file

I am having a string of format `101514,101234,101645,101798`. I want to split the string on `,` and then loop through each of the individual elements comparing that element with the required value.

```
set required_value=1024
for /f  "delims=," %%a in ("101514,101234,101645,101798") do (
    set found=%%a
    if "%found%"=="%required_value%" (
        echo true
    ) else (
        echo false
    )
)
```

Here obviously, only first part is considered. I can use `"tokens=1,2,3"` and then `%%a`, `%%b`, `%%c` so on to compare, but the length is not fixed.

Is there any other way to solve it.

Comment: This question for a simple task turned out to be extremely useful for many use cases in my estimation because of the answers. The techniques demonstrated by [aschipfl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) and [Aacini](http://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) in their answers are awesome, not very efficient for this task, but nevertheless really worth the time studying them with `echo on`. I can only suggest for every visitor to look on all answers. They are all great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a different method without a loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "RequiredValue=1024"
set "ValuesList=101514,101234,101645,101798"
rem Prepend and append a comma on value list.
set "AllValues=,%ValuesList%,"
rem Use substring replacement to find out if the required
rem value is included in list of values or is missing in list.
if "!AllValues:,%RequiredValue%,=!" == "%AllValues%" (
    echo %RequiredValue% not found in %ValuesList%
) else (
    echo %RequiredValue% is included in %ValuesList%
)
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 2):

- use plain `for` without `/f "delims"`
- don't quote the string
- don't assign to `found` variable, it won't work without delayed expansion inside the loop, use `%%a`

---

```
for %%a in (101514,101234,101645,101798) do (
    if "%%a"=="%required_value%" (
        echo true
    ) else (
        echo false
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to use a plain `for` command (no `/F` switch) as suggested by wOxxOm.

A more efficient method is to replace the required value from the list, as Mofi described in his answer.

There is another method that only works when the values are numbers. The trick consist in assemble an arithmetic expression that subtract the required value from each one of the values in the list, and then multiply all partial results; if the required value is one of the list, the result is zero.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "ValuesList=101514,101234,101645,101798"

rem Create the test function
set "IsValueInList(x)=(%ValuesList:,=-x)*(%-x)"

rem Test if a value is in list
set "RequiredValue=1024"
set /A "test=%IsValueInList(x):x=RequiredValue%"

if %test% equ 0 (
   echo true
) else (
   echo false
)
```

This program uses two interesting tricks: the definition of a Batch "function" as described at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6744), and a special way to "split a string on delimiter" as explained [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is using `call` to run a subroutine, which uses `shift`:

```
set required_value=1024
set list_of_values=101514,101234,101645,101798

call :SUBSPLIT %list_of_values%
echo %found%
exit /B

:SUBSPLIT
set found=false
:LOOP
if "%1"=="" (
    exit /B
) else if "%1"=="%required_value%" (
    set found=true
    exit /B
)
shift
goto :LOOP
```

Type `call /?` and `shift /?` in the command prompt to get mote information about the core commands of this approach.